# FFMPEG m3u8 encoding change extension of TS files to something else

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, m3u8

I'm using below command to encrypt a MP4 video into a m3u8 type.

```
const cmd = "ffmpeg";
const args = [
  "-i",
  `${input}`,
  "-c",
  "copy",
  "-bsf:v",
  "h264_mp4toannexb",
  "-hls_list_size",
  "0",
  "-hls_time",
  "10",
  "-hls_key_info_file",
  "enc.keyinfo",
  `output/${outputFileName}.m3u8`,
];
```

This works and output the data.but is there any possible way to tell ffmpeg to not add `.TS` extensions to the playlist items ?

I manually update one of the playlist item in `m3u8` file with some random file extension and it works.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://localhost/key/video.key",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
#EXTINF:10.666667,
somerandomname // <-- Here I change it and when I play in a HLS player it works. 
#EXTINF:11.666667,
output1.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Can I do this with the above command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution,

There's a flag for do that. You can use,

```
'-hls_segment_filename', 'segment%d'
```

`%d` is incrementing number so this will save files as `segment0`, `segment1`, `segment2`, `...`, `segnemntN`.